# SQL Server Stretch database, and archiving table to SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition

We have a generic need: A large, growing table.

For performance reasons, we want to move obsolete/old data out to an archive table.

SQL Azure would be the perfect home.

The question is:  Should we use a table in a "stretch" db (new in SQL 2016), or should we simply manage this in application code?

Comment: What I really think you should do is to test your different scenarios. With a well-indexed table, size increase shouldn't lead to noticeable deterioration in performance. It would help with backup times - but, you can check this out - preferably on a test system of similar size - if you have one. But, without testing information, any suggestions would be just opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Stretch table could be good fit for your need. However i suggest to check the current limitations of enabling stretch feature.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt605114.aspx

The other manual way of doing this is partitioning the table and switching out to another table in the same DB.